# How do you reconcile IDisposable and IoC?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, idisposable

I'm finally wrapping my head around IoC and DI in C#, and am struggling with some of the edges.  I'm using the Unity container, but I think this question applies more broadly.

Using an IoC container to dispense instances that implement IDisposable freaks me out!  How are you supposed to know if you should Dispose()?  The instance might have been created just for you (and therefor you should Dispose() it), or it could be an instance whose lifetime is managed elsewhere (and therefor you'd better not).  Nothing in the code tells you, and in fact this could change based on configuration!!!  This seems deadly to me.

Can any IoC experts out there describe good ways to handle this ambiguity?

Comment: My solution is to use a IoC with proper and well-codified lifetime management: AutoFac and Castle Windsor have such (although they work slightly differently); Unit 2.1 simply fails when dealing with transients under the default lifetime managers ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[AutoFac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) handles this by allowing the creation of a nested container. When the container is finished with, it automatically disposes of all IDisposable objects within it. More [here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetime/index.html).

> .. As you resolve services, Autofac tracks disposable (IDisposable) components that are resolved. *At the end of the unit of work, you dispose of the associated lifetime scope and Autofac will automatically clean up/dispose of the resolved services.*

Comment: Very interesting.  I didn't know anything abaout AutoFac.  I don't think it would be too hard to do something like this with Unity.  I'm going to have to think about this one a bit.  Thanks!

Comment: It might be hard to do that with Unity, since deterministic disposal has been embedded into the architecture of Autofac since the beginning.

Comment: Castle Windsor is the other container that lets you do that, either using sub-container, scoped lifestyle or via explicitly releasing your components using `container.Release` method

Comment: StructureMap also has a nested container concept to deal with this issue. However, its only for tranients, it won't dispose things scoped at the http context level (there's a method call which does that) or Singletons (completely up to you).

Comment: AutoFac always seems to be per-container/lifetime-scope IDisposable-lifetimes (which works quite well and, *unlike Unity*, it does offer eventual cleanup of transients). Castle Windsor can [also] release sub-trees of components without need to create explicit scopes which is useful when implementing things like factories. (But for this to work as advertised and allow early-releasing, there must be explicit "factory.Release" calls, so in part it shifts ownership.)

Answer (score 17):

You definitely do not want to call Dispose() on an object that was injected into your class. You can't make the assumption that you are the only consumer. Your best bet is to wrap your unmanaged object in some managed interface:

```
public class ManagedFileReader : IManagedFileReader
{
    public string Read(string path)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

That is just an example, I would use File.ReadAllText(path) if I were trying to read a text file into a string.

Another approach is to inject a factory and manage the object yourself:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    using (var resourceThatShouldBeDisposed = injectedFactory.CreateResource())
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: But I do want to inject IDisposable objects, and further, I may or may not need to Dispose() of them at the site of injection, depending on configuration.

Your first example works when the underlying resource is accessed transiently, but doesn't help if the resource is more persistent. 

In the second example, it seems odd to me to inject a factory in this way; that is one of the major functions of the IoC model in the first place.  If I apply IoC to this concept, I seem to end up back at the original question.  I think the container itself needs to participate in this, a la AutoFac.

Comment: @Mr. Putty - dependency injection doesn't eliminate the need for factories, it just makes one (ab)use of them unnecessary. For example, when you don't know the type of the concrete dependency until runtime, or for expensive conditional dependencies (objects that you might not even need which take a lot of resources to create), you might want to inject a factory instead of the object itself.  Depending on your DI framework's support for IDisposable, factory injection may be the best way - it's certainly more transparent than many of the alternatives. (+1)

Comment: I think this is good advice. Never inject IDisposables directly; use managed wrappers instead - or, use a life time that allows explicit disposal in specific cases like a db context, like HttpContextScoped in StructureMap or PerRequestLifetimeManager in Unity.

Comment: @L-Three *And* use an IoC container that actually understands IDisposable lifetimes .. but there be quirks when disposables are disposed. The only "sure" method I've found so far is something like Castle and [typed] factories: while transients will be eventually released from the root (ie. no "overall" resource leak) the only way to ensure immediate sub-graph disposal is with a "factory.Release" strategy. However, this is better than trying to deal with IDisposable services directly: 1) the lifetime is still handled by the IoC; 2) the consumer is agnostic to the component being disposable.

Answer (score 4):

This has puzzled me frequently as well. Though not happy about it, I always came to the conclusion that never returning an IDisposable object in a transient way was best.

Recently, I rephrased the question for myself: Is this really an IoC issue, or a .net framework issue? Disposing is awkward anyway. It has no meaningful functional purpose, only technical. So it's more a framework issue that we have to deal with, than an IoC issue.

What I like about DI is that I can ask for a contract providing me functionality, without having to bother about the technical details. I'm not the owner. No knowledge about which layer it's in. No knowledge about which technologies are required to fulfil the contract, no worries about lifetime. My code looks nice and clean, and is highly testable. I can implement responsibilities in the layers where they belong.

So if there's an exception to this rule that does require me to organise the lifetime, let's make that exception. Whether I like it or not. If the object implementing the interface requires me to dispose it, I want to know about it since then I am triggered to use the object as short as possible. A trick by resolving it using a child container which is disposed some time later on might still cause me keeping the object alive longer than I should. The allowed lifetime of the object is determined when registering the object. Not by the functionality that creates a child container and holds on to that for a certain period.

So as long as we developers need to worry about disposing (will that ever change?) I will try to inject as few transient disposable objects as possible. 
1.  I try to make the object not IDisposable, for example by not keeping disposable objects on class level, but in a smaller scope.
2.  I try to make the object reusable so that a different lifetime manager can be applied.

If this is not feasible, I use a factory to indicate that the user of the injected contract is owner and should take responsibility for it.

There is one caveat: changing a contract implementer from non-disposable to disposable will be a breaking change. At that time the interface will no longer be registered, but the interface to the factory. But I think this applies to other scenario's as well. Forgetting to use a child container will from that moment on give memory issues. The factory approach will cause an IoC resolve exception.

Some example code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace Test
{
    // Unity configuration
    public class ConfigurationExtension : UnityContainerExtension
    {
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // Container.RegisterType<IDataService, DataService>(); Use factory instead
            Container.RegisterType<IInjectionFactory<IDataService>, InjectionFactory<IDataService, DataService>>();
        }
    }

    #region General utility layer

    public interface IInjectionFactory<out T>
        where T : class
    {
        T Create();
    }

    public class InjectionFactory<T2, T1> : IInjectionFactory<T2>
        where T1 : T2
        where T2 : class

    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer _iocContainer;

        public InjectionFactory(IUnityContainer iocContainer)
        {
            _iocContainer = iocContainer;
        }

        public T2 Create()
        {
            return _iocContainer.Resolve<T1>();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region data layer

    public class DataService : IDataService, IDisposable
    {
        public object LoadData()
        {
            return "Test data";
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                /* Dispose stuff */
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region domain layer

    public interface IDataService
    {
        object LoadData();
    }

    public class DomainService
    {
        private readonly IInjectionFactory<IDataService> _dataServiceFactory;

        public DomainService(IInjectionFactory<IDataService> dataServiceFactory)
        {
            _dataServiceFactory = dataServiceFactory;
        }

        public object GetData()
        {
            var dataService = _dataServiceFactory.Create();
            try
            {
                return dataService.LoadData();
            }
            finally
            {
                var disposableDataService = dataService as IDisposable;
                if (disposableDataService != null)
                {
                    disposableDataService.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in general the best approach is to simply not Dispose of something which has been injected; you have to assume that the injector is doing the allocation and deallocation.

Comment: This is very inconvenient, as I frequently want to inject disposable objects.  In general, the semantics of IDisposable require the creator/owner of the object to Dispose of it at the right time.  If the container is responsible, then the user of the instance needs to tell the container when it's done.  This is easy to forget.

Comment: Downvoted, as the latter part of your answer is bad.  Most containers have a way to handle this, either nested containers or something like StructureMaps `ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects` method.  You still need to figure out how disposables are going to be properly disposed... unless you like running out of connections and such.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the DI framework.  Some frameworks allow you to specify whether you want a shared instance (always using the same reference) for every dependency injected.  In this case, you most likely do not want to dispose.

If you can specify that you want a unique instance injected, then you will want to dispose (since it was being constructed for you specifically).  I'm not as familiar with Unity, though - you'd have to check the docs as to how to make this work there.  It's part of the attribute with MEF and some others I've tried, though.

Answer (score 2):

Putting a facade in front of the container can resolve this as well. Plus you can extend it to keep track of a more rich life cycle like service shutdowns and startups or ServiceHost state transitions.

My container tends to live in an IExtension that implements the IServiceLocator interface. It is a facade for unity, and allows for easy access in WCf services. Plus I have access to the service events from the ServiceHostBase.

The code you end up with will attempt to see if any singleton registered or any type created implements any of the interfaces that the facade keeps track of.

Still does not allow for the disposing in a timely manner as you are tied to these events but it helps a bit.

If you want to dispose in a timely manner (aka, now v.s. upon service shutdown). You need to know that the item you get is disposable, it is part of the business logic to dispose of it, so IDisposable should be part of the interface of the object. And there probably should be verification of expectations untitests related to the dispose method getting called.

Comment: Don't you loose the advantage of constructor injection this way?

Answer (score 1):

In the Unity framework, there are two ways to register the injected classes: as singletons (you get always the same instance of the class when you resolve it), or such as you get a new instance of the class on each resolution.

In the later case, you have the responsibility of disposing the resolved instance once you don't need it (which is a quite reasonable approach). On the other hand, when you dispose the container (the class that handles object resolutions), all the singleton objects are automatically disposed as well.

Therefore, there are apparently no issues with injected disposable objects with the Unity framework. I don't know about other frameworks, but I suppose that as long as a dependency injection framework is solid enough, it for sure handles this issue in one way or another.

Comment: Great article on this: http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/unity-build-in-lifetime-managers/

Comment: It is a *terrible* approach, nothing "reasonable" about having injected-and-untracked-objects that need to be disposed. This is complicated because it is further not possible for components to manually Dispose their injected dependencies because the lifetime is unknown - singleton, transient, etc. Unity (2.x) flat out fails in that under standard lifetimes transients are never disposed by the container.

Comment: "In the latter case..." The client does not know wether it's the first or latter case, and should not know. It should stay unaware of the chosen lifetime of the injected object. I don't agree with the remark of user2864740 that Unity fails. I think it's a framework characteristic that we have to deal with, unfortunately.