# How to Inject Open Connections with an IoC

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container

First, my scenario.  I have a service, BillingService, has a constructor like this:

BillingService(IInstallmentService, IBillingRepository)

The InstallmentService has a constructor that looks like this

InstallmentService(IBillingRepository, IInstallmentCalculator)

My Billing service is an application service and the methods will coordinate the operation between the moving pieces.  Everything is registered in my IoC container so that my facade only has to resolve an IBillingService and call the operation.

My BillingService and installment service both need to access the BillingRepository.  I should only have to open one DB connection, so ideally the BillingRepository would take an IDbCOnnection in the constructor.

My question is, how do I get an open connection passed into my BillingRepository from my container and then effectively close it after my BillingService is done with it?  I'm stuck with Unity at this client.  If I were writing this by hand, it would looke like this:

```
using(IDbConnection conn = DbFactory.GetConnection())
{
     IBillingRepository repo = new BillingRepository(conn);
     IInstallmentCalculator calc = new InstallmentCalculator();
     IInstallmentService installmentService = new InstallmentService(repo,calc);
     IBillingService billService = new BillingService(installmentService, repo);

     billService.DoSomething(parameters);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd introduce a dependency on the connection into the `BillingRepository`, just like in your example, but let Unity create the connection.

Make sure `BillingRepository` implements `IDisposable` (possibly the billing service too), and set it up as a transient object (however that's expressed in Unity).

If the billing repository maintains some state that needs a longer lifetime (for example, for the life of the application), I'd factor that out into another class and make the billing repository dependent on that too.

Comment: I was considering that as well, but there is no guarantee of when the GC may come along and dispose.  That could leave me with a needless open DB connection for who knows how long.

Comment: Hmm, I may not understand the context in which it will be used. I'm proposing this for situations in which you control when dispose is called - either through your IoC infrastructure, or by disposing of the top-level objects that you do have access too (e.g., your billing *service*, which would have to implement IDisposable too). There was a good discussion here about IoC and disposables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987761/how-do-you-reconcile-idisposable-and-ioc.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  That occurred to me shortly after I wrote my comment.  It seemed strange at first, but I guess it really isn't.  I'll checkout the link.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Unity, but I would keep connection details to your BillingRepository and pass the open connection via a property to your other objects.

So in your container create a property that returns a BillingRepository object and then you can access your open connection through that property in any other object.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That solution is the first that came to my mind as well.  I disagree that the connection details have to be created in my repository.  What if I have an operation that uses 2 repositories?  Now I have 2 open connections. I see nothing wrong with the Application Service managing those infrastructure details and is a very common amongst DDD patterns.

Comment: Ok, then you can just create a property that returns the object that maintains your connections in the container you have.